# Rigid structure for the category of infinite-dimensional vector spaces

Tags: vector-spaces, category-theory, monoidal-categories

The category of finite-dimensional vector spaces, endowed with its usual tensor product, is rigid, that is it admits right and left duals. What happens in the infinite-dimensional case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing good. No infinite dimensional vector space is isomorphic to its double dual in the linear algebraic sense, so there are no such vector spaces which admit duals in the categorical sense.

Comment: Is $X\cong (X^*)^*$ part of the definition of a rigid category?

Comment: @NDewolf Isn't it automatic for a symmetric monoidal category ?

Comment: If you also take into account that the category $Vect$ is symmetric then yes, the argument is indeed sound.